# TypeError: undefined is not a function while using PayPal

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, callback

I'm getting following error while using sample examples mentioned here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_plans/create.js.

> ```
>         return callback(null, billingPlan.id);
>                ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
> at /home/mukul/scrub/server/payments/paypal/paypal.controller.js:241:17
> at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/mukul/scrub/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:131:13)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
> at _stream_readable.js:908:16
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
> ```

Following is my code:

```
function createBillingPlan(planDesc, planAmount, planFrequency, planName, planCurrency, callback) { 
   var billingPlanAttributes = {
    "description": planDesc,
    "merchant_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_amount": "yes",
        "cancel_url": CANCEL_URL,
        "initial_fail_amount_action": "continue",
        "max_fail_attempts": "1",
        "return_url": RETURN_URL
    },
    "name": planName,
    "payment_definitions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": 25
            },
            "charge_models": [
                {
                    "amount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 2
                    },
                    "type": "SHIPPING"
                },
                {
                    "amount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value":27
                    },
                    "type": "TAX"
                }
            ],
            "cycles": "0",
            "frequency": frequency,
            "frequency_interval": "1",
            "name": planName,
            "type": "REGULAR"
        },
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "0"
            },
            "cycles": "1",
            "frequency": "MONTH",
            "frequency_interval": "1",
            "name": "Trial",
            "type": "TRIAL"
        }
    ],
    "type": "INFINITE"
};

paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttributes, function (error, billingPlan) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error);  // This is causing error
    } else {
        console.log("Create Billing Plan Response");
        console.log(billingPlan);
        return callback(null, billingPlan.id); // this is causing error
    }
});
```

}
Any idea how can I resolve the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `callback` to be? it's ***undefined*** in your code.

Comment: @Amit: How is it undefined ? Didn't get it. Can you please why is it undefined ? I'm having callback as a function param and then using it. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi, Can you post the code that calls this method? probably you are forgetting a parameter or just setting this param to undefined.